# Get info from JSON file and turn it into a PHP String

Tags: php, json, audio, webfm-api

I want to connect with the last fm API and pulling the information from the JSON file.

Example file : [Last FM API JSON File][1]

on my php file I get the correct information via this code :

```
<?$get = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?
method=artist.getinfo&artist=Ed 
Sheeran&api_key=63692beaaf8ba794a541bca291234cd3&format=json');
$get = json_decode($get);
foreach($get->artist->tags->tag as $tags) { $thetag = (array) $thetag;?>
<? echo $thetag['name'];?> 
<?} ?>
```

At the moment this will echo each individual tag for that artist, for example : easy listening and grime

What i am wondering is there any way to create a string that contains $thetag whilst also putting a comma inbetween?

```
$newstring = "easy listening, grime"
```

e.t.c

My plan is to create the string and then use php code to search my database and display records where the tag column contains any of those tags. Any idea how is it possible?

[1]: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Ed Sheeran&api_key=63692beaaf8ba794a541bca291234cd3&format=json

Comment: Please, edit your question so that the code parts look like code (indent four spaces). Also, mark code within text with ``. Thanks.

Comment: @JavierElices has that worked?

Comment: Are you seriously telling us that the code you have posted Works?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw what are you on about? I asked javier if what they had asked was done correctly.

Comment: @JohnMartyn, your question has bits that should be code and are not. Do you know how to edit your question to fix it?

Comment: @JohnMartyn What are you on about? Your PHP Code does not work! Plain and simple! Which shows me you have not even bothered to run it!

Comment: @TimBrownlaw - Yes the code does not work, hence why I am here asking for help. Tim, you're very confusing.

Comment: @JohnMartyn I am only pointing out that you have clearly stated: "on my php file I get the correct information via this code :" which means that you are telling us that the code is working... anyway...

Comment: @JohnMartyn Don't forget to remove API key from the text of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tested and working and is one of a few possible methods...

```
<?php
$song_list_json = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Ed Sheeran&api_key=63692beaaf8ba794a541bca291234cd3&format=json');
$song_list = json_decode($song_list_json);

$name_tags = array();
foreach ($song_list->artist->tags->tag as $tags) {
    $name_tags[] = $tags->name;
}
$song_names = implode(', ',$name_tags);

// Do something with it...
echo $song_names;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the JSON string as array. Then use `array_map` function to iterate through `$array['artist']['tags']['tag']` array to get only `name` values.

```
// $json contains JSON string from API response to ws.audioscrobbler.com.
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$tags = '';

if (!empty($array['artist']['tags']['tag'])) {
    $tags = array_map(
        function($tag) {
            return isset($tag['name']) ? $tag['name'] : '';
        }, $array['artist']['tags']['tag']);
    $tags = implode(', ', $tags);
}
```

Comment: Have tried this, but it seems if i then echo $tags; 

I get no response and the error 
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'name'.

Not too sure why, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @JohnMartyn, inside function in `array_map` replace `return $tag['name'];` to `return isset($tag['name']) ? $tag['name'] : '';`